# How to iterate object knowing value type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

I have a dictionary of UI changes that come from the API:

```js
interface UIChangesDictionary {
    christmasTreeCount: number;
    greeting: string;
    isDarkMode: boolean;
}
```

Let's use static object to make things easier:

```js
const changes: UIChangesDictionary = {
    christmasTreeCount: 14,
    greeting: "Ho ho ho",
    isDarkMode: true,
};
```

Now, in my API handler, I'd like to iterate over these changes and apply appropriate UI changes:

```js
Object.entries(changes).forEach(
    ([ property, value ]) => {
        switch (property) {
            case "christmasTreeCount":
                // value should be number
                break;
            case "greeting":
                // value should be string
                break;
            case "isDarkMode":
                // value should be boolean
                break;
        }
    }
);
```

Unfortunately, the `value` is always `any`. I thought `Object.entries()` would be able to infer the type properly, but it can't.

How would I implement it to have `value` use a type from its interface?

Comment: seems strange to use a switch in a forEach since you may as well just access the properties directly at that point.

Comment: I know, but in reality this object would come from the API and wouldn't include all of the properties. I need to apply all changes that are included in that object.

Comment: Even so I would still probably access them individually and act on them if not `undefined`. But for your loop you can iterate the `Object.keys()` and access the value in the switch which will properly infer types due to the case. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Na4R9w)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid those repeating `changes[property]`?

Answer (score -1):

- You can use a type assertion or type graud.

```
Object.entries(changes).forEach(([property, value]) => {
  const change = value as UIChangesDictionary;
  switch (property) {
    case 'christmasTreeCount':
      // value should be number
      console.log(change);
      break;
    case 'greeting':
      console.log(change);
      break;
    case 'isDarkMode':
      console.log(change);
      break;
  }
});
```

or type graud.

```
Object.entries(changes).forEach(([property, value]) => {
  switch (property) {
    case 'christmasTreeCount':
      if (typeof value === 'number') {
        const count = value;
        console.log(count);
      }
      break;
    case 'greeting':
      break;
    case 'isDarkMode':
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: In the first example, `value` is of type `UIChangesDictionary`, which is not what I need. Second example means repeating all types, which is even worse.